# How to Edit a record through JS and AJAX using .NET 6 and DATATABLE

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-core, datatable, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to edit a record that is displayed in the datatable through javascript.

My idea is to edit a table record with javascript. I understand that  tags helper are not used in this case and that is when the problem arose.

My idea is to do something like get the id of the record and it can do the same as this code:

```
<a asp-controller="Person" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@obj.Id" class="btn btn-warning mx-3">Editar</a>
```

The @obj.id is through an iterator that I had put in tbody. It is the most common way to do it in net core.

The point is that I can't find a way to replace those tag helpers.

controller edit action:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Edit(int? id) 
    {
        if(id == null || id == 0 ) return NotFound();

        var PersonFromDb = _db.Persons.Find(id);

        if(PersonFromDb == null) return NotFound();

        return View(PersonFromDb);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Edit(Person obj)
    {
        if (obj.Name == obj.LastName)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("LastName", "Last name cannot be the same as first name.");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(obj);

        _db.Persons.Update(obj);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        TempData["success"] = "Successfully Updated Person!";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

At the end of the Index view I have a script where I was working to make the edit button of the datatable work. Index view:

```
<div class="container p-3">
        <div class="row pt-4">
            <div class="col-6">
                <h2 class="text-primary">Persons</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 text-end">
                <a asp-controller="Person" asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary"> 
                    Add Person
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    
    <table id="datatable" class="display cell-border compact" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Years</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="BodyData"></tbody>
    </table>
    
    @section Scripts{
        <script>
        
            let table = new DataTable('#datatable', {
                "ajax":{
                    "url": "@Url.Action("GetData", "Person")",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "contentType": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 
                    "datatype": "json", 
                    "dataSrc": "", 
                },
                "columns": [
                   {"data": 'id'},
                   {"data": 'name'},
                   {"data": 'lastName'},
                   {"data": 'year'},
                   {"render": function (data, row) { 
                           const edit = "<a href='#' class='btn btn-warning'>Edit)</a>"; 
                           return edit
                       }
                   },
                ],  
            });
        </script>
    }
```

Here is the edit view:

```
@model Person

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}
    
<form method="post" asp-action="Edit">
    <div class="border p-3 m-4">
        <div class="row pb-2">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Update Person</h2>
            <hr/>
        </div>

        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Name"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="LastName"></label>
            <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Year"></label>
            <input asp-for="Year" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Year" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px">Update</button>
        <a asp-controller="Person" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width:150px">Back</a>
    </div>

</form>
 
@section Scripts{
    @{
        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer. Just add the corresponding URL to the Edit href and pass the id.

```
   {"render": function (data, type, full, meta) { 
        const edit = `<a href='/Person/Edit/${full.id}' class='btn btn-warning'>Edit)</a>`; 
        return edit
     }
     },
```